# How can I make my PhoneGap android app onPause by overwriting BackButton?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, onpause, localnotification

I'm trying to develop an android app with phonegap and LocalNotification plugin.
I want to running my app in onPause , 
On my index.html

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
```

function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event

```
setInterval( function() {
    Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: 'http://convert4mobile.net/backend/API/qr/push.php',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data.success == true)
                {
                    if (typeof plugins !== "undefined") {
              window.plugins.localNotification.add({
                        date : new Date(),
                        message : data.time+"\r\n"+data.msg,
                        ticker : "A new code was generated",
                        repeatDaily : false,
                        id : 4
                });
                }
                }
            }
           });
} , 2000);
```

}

It works fine when the app was closed/minimized by home button/end call button.
I want to do the same thing by BackButton tapping.
Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter whatever code you want in this method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Tutorial Here: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-10%E2%80%93The-Back-Button

Comment: I have tried `@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true); 
  return; 
}` the app was running on background but onPause was not working

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean, could you try to reword that?

Comment: Please see my posted question , I want to run a javascript in background . I want to run a setInterval method to get notification from server when the was not running.